# Express sendFile function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write some API using node.js. I have a pdf file stored in Temp folder, and I want to send it using res.sendFile(). But when i try so, it just sends back empty file (not even pdf file), with no error.

I have already tried using both relative and absolute path.

```
res.sendFile(`${os.tmpdir}/download/something.pdf`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide the path via the `options` parameter.  Example code:

```
app.get('/file', function (req, res, next) {
  var options = {
    root: `${os.tmpdir}`,
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
      'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
      'x-sent': true
    }
  }

  var filename = 'somefile.pdf'

  res.sendFile(filename, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName)
    }
  })
})
```

Code based on: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it still doesnt work for me. Even if I try exactly the same code that you posted, I get the same result.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` with the output being the full location of the PDF?  Then go to that location and confirm that the file is there.  Just want to make sure the code is pointing to the correct location/file.

Comment: I double checked it and the destination is correct. I tried some changes too and finally, it was sending the file back, but every time the app sent the file, it crashed too. It crashed with following error:

Comment: I would need more code that what you provided to troubleshoot that error.  There is no "done" in the code provided.

Comment: Exactly. I just used the code posted here, without any done function, but still, I get this error. There is no "done" in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have an invalid file path. Try using the `__dirname` global to make the path to the file relative to the directory in which you are executing your node script.

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/download/something.pdf");
```